# How can I un-enqueue a javascript file in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm working with Wordpress site and a script that I have to have is breaking a plugin that I also have to have lol.

What would be the best way to have that script not run when I'm on pages that use the plugin? Every page that has the plugin has "?fl_builder" on the end of the URL

I was thinking maybe use jQuery to have the script not run if the url contains "?fl_builder"? I'm just not sure how to write it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are either of the two plugins yours? If not, you'll probably want to make a third plugin which has some code to mitigate the collision.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried added a $_GET variable where you call your script?

Example:

```
if(isset($_GET['fl_builder'])) { wp_register_script(...); }
```

Comment: The script is called in the two plugins the OP "has to have". He probably can't modify them.